# How to prevent the page refresh while submitting the form?

Tags: javascript

Requirement:
There are two drop down boxes. Dropdown2 should load corresponding to the select of Dropdown1.

I'm hitting a db for this every time. Hence the page loads every time when changing Dropdown1.

Is there any way in JavaScript to prevent this page loading?

Answer (score 3):

To do this you need to use AJAX, which translates to using a JavaScript framework (all decent ones offer rich AJAX functionality and much more). Today, for most people this means using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Take a look at [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174334/populate-a-dropdown-select-based-on-the-value-chosen-on-another-dropdown) as a starting point for how to implement the solution (you might also need to see some jQuery tutorials if you are completely unfamiliar with it). There is also much more material for linked dropdown menus both here on SO and all over the internet -- searching will give you lots of good results.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. I was going to give a very similar answer  :)

Comment: Hi.But Im not having ajax in my workspace.Do i need to import any jar files for that?

Comment: @Tom: I have no idea what jar files you are talking about. This question doesn't mention Java at all, and Java**Script** has totally no relation to Java.

Comment: Sorry... I mean any other files that needs to be imported to work in ajax?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="proc_form();return false" />
```

That's all!

Comment: What is `proc_form` supposed to do?

Comment: custom form proccessing. His own function. I think that he have button there (form) for purpose?

Comment: thank you so much genesis for making it clear where to put the 'return false;'. this took me days.. :) thanks much!...i can now proceed :)